# Detect feature suport with modernizer and process with PHP based on result

Tags: php, wordpress, modernizr

So I need to detect webp support using modernizer, and then do some processign in PHP depending on the outcome of the result.

Now at first I thought I could set a cookie and get the cookie using PHP like so:

JS:

```
Modernizr.on('webp', function (result) {
  if (result) {
    setCookie("webpissupported", "yes", "365");
  }
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

PHP:

```
$userAvatar = um_get_avatar_uri( um_profile('profile_photo'), 190 );
$patterns = array("/.jpg/", "/.jpeg/", "/.png/");
if (isset($_COOKIE['webpsupport']))
    $userAvatar = preg_replace($patterns, "_result.webp", $userAvatar);
```

Now the problem with the above code is that I'm using the wordpress plugin w3 total cache, with the page cache enabled. this is causing the cookie to be cached and producing unexpected results.

So then I thought maybe I could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Modernizr.on("webp", function (result) {
      if (result) {
        <?php $webpSupport = true; ?>
      }
    });
</script>
```

But this will not work.

Anyone know how I might get around this problem.

Comment: The problem is that they run in the wrong order. PHP runs first, creates the page, sends it to the browser, then Modernizer runs. The only way to do this is for PHP to send a page that runs Modernizer and then submits the page back as a form.

Comment: @Barmar hi, do you have a rough example of how to do this. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed (client) browser-side processing with server-side (PHP). In your example, PHP block of code shall be executed regardless of what is to be *processed later* by browser/JS (or won't at all, in case of no `JS` browser). So, `$webpSupport` variable in this case and example shall be what you assign to it in order from top to bottom.

One way to achieve what you are after is to have JS cookie set, `setCookie("webpissupported", "yes", "365");` and in the next page view read the `$_COOKIE['webpissupported']` and serve images according to it.

Remember, `webp` is not a standard, although present in 72.85% browsers according to caniuse.com /StatCounter. You have to use it as progressive enhancement.